# Get data of a post method Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, post, callback

I'm using an API which is sending me a callback to an URL, this route uses a POST method, I just want to see the data that the callback is sending to me through that URL.

I saw the data and the response of the API and it appears the callback status as a success. So, I just want to see what's inside it.

How can I do that?

**This is my route/web.php**

```
Route::post('/callback', [
    'uses' => 'PackController@callback',
    'as' => 'payment.callback'
]);
```

**And this is the function in my controller**

```
public function callback(Request $request) {
        dd(json_decode($request->getContent(), true));
        return view('payment.callback');
}
```

**I'm getting this error too, I think that it's because of the method of the route.** 
[image]

**These are the instructions to receive the callback**
https://developer.coingate.com/docs/payment-callback

Comment: What is this `dump()` function? Did you mean `var_dump()` or `dd()`?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-dump

Comment: I tried this, but it's not working yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public function callback(Request $request) {
    var_dump($request->all());
    die(1);
    return view('payment.callback');
}
```

I suggest you use debugger (XDebug).
You can add breakpoint and view all variables, global variables, constants other details.

Comment: How can I use a debugger?

Comment: Your idea is throwing me an empty array

Comment: What IDE do you use?

You should install xdebug PHP extention, and setup your IDE.

You can read this tutorial:
https://deliciousbrains.com/xdebug-advanced-php-debugging/

Comment: If you prefer to watch video tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSSjeelN5NU

Comment: Ohh, I understand, but in this case. I just want to see what's the data inside the callback because I'm trying it in web server.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not testing it in my localhost.

Comment: POST data?
Are you sure there is data? `$request->all()` should return Input data if this data exists and not filtered.

Comment: I’m just following the instructions of the API. It says that it’s going to send a callback to this URL with the POST method, it appears that the callback response was successful and shows the data. I just want to request it inside my website.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're making a request to some API, and that API is later making a request back to your code.  If this is all server-side, then `dump()` isn't going to give *you* any information, it's just going to dump data in the response to the remote service that's making the POST to your server.

Instead of `dump()`ing, try logging it:

```
public function callback(Request $request) {
     Log::info("Received callback", $request->input());
     die();
}
```

Then take a look at the log file.

Comment: I think it's not going to work because I'm not doing this in my localhost, I'm testing it a web server-

Comment: Well, you need to put the data somewhere you can get it.  If you can't read `/tmp` on the server (shared hosting?), you can stick it somewhere else.  Either create a directory with permissions that allow PHP to write to it, or stick it in an S3 bucket, or POST it somewhere else, or insert it in a database... it's really up to you.  The key thing to understand is the your PHP code can't send a response to your browser when the request isn't coming from your browser.

Comment: So, which is the best way to get a callback with Laravel? Because I’m just trying to get the data which is coming from the API

Comment: I've updated my answer to use Laravel's `Log` facility.  When the remote server POSTs to your server, you should get an entry in laravel's log, which IIRC is in `storage/log/laravel.log` or something.

Comment: I tried, but it's not showing anythings in the log file.

Comment: Then there are two possibilities: your logging infrastructure is broken, or the remote API isn't actually POSTing to the callback URL.  Does anything get written to the log if you POST to the callback yourself (using curl or postman or something?)

Comment: I think it's POSTing correctly, what I wonder if we're catching correctly the data of the callback?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185632/discussion-between-timdev-and-danhergir).